# How would I import .pkl.gz file from my computer into a python program

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tflearn

I have my own data set that I want to train my model on. I have successfully created .pk.gz files but I don't know how would I import them into my model.

I am using a windows 10, python 3.5.2 with tensor-flow and tflearn and sublime text 3 to write code.

The code I used to create the pickle file:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt

import gzip
import _pickle as cPickle

#data = sio.loadmat('C:/DeepLearning_lib/Theano/Data/test_x.mat')

train_set_x = genfromtxt('C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/MachineLearning/dataset/NSL-KDD Processed/Kdd_Train_41.csv', delimiter=',')

train_set_y = genfromtxt('C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/MachineLearning/dataset/NSL-KDD Processed/NSL_TrainLabels_mat4.csv', delimiter=',')

valid_set_x = genfromtxt('C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/MachineLearning/dataset/NSL-KDD Processed/Kdd_Valid_41.csv', delimiter=',')

valid_set_y = genfromtxt('C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/MachineLearning/dataset/NSL-KDD Processed/NSL_ValidLabels_int2.csv', delimiter=',')

test_set_x = genfromtxt('C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/MachineLearning/dataset/NSL-KDD Processed/Kdd_Test_41.csv', delimiter=',')

test_set_y = genfromtxt('C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/MachineLearning/dataset/NSL-KDD Processed/NSL_TestLabels_mat5.csv', delimiter=',')



train_set = test_set_x
train_set_labels= test_set_y

valid_set = valid_set_x
valid_set_labels= valid_set_y

test_set = train_set_x
test_set_labels= train_set_y


f = gzip.open('C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/Data/train_set.pkl.gz','wb')
cPickle.dump(train_set, f, protocol=2)

f.close()

f = gzip.open('C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/Data/train_set_labels.pkl.gz','wb')
cPickle.dump(train_set_labels, f, protocol=2)

f.close()

f = gzip.open('C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/Data/valid_set_labels.pkl.gz','wb')
cPickle.dump(valid_set_labels, f, protocol=2)

f.close()
f = gzip.open('C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/Data/test_set_labels.pkl.gz','wb')
cPickle.dump(test_set_labels, f, protocol=2)

f.close()
f = gzip.open('C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/Data/valid_set.pkl.gz','wb')
cPickle.dump(valid_set, f, protocol=2)

f.close()
f = gzip.open('C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/Data/test_set.pkl.gz','wb')
cPickle.dump(test_set, f, protocol=2)

f.close()
```

Errors : when used 'rb'

```
'OSError: [Errno 9] peek() on write-only GzipFile object'
```

Comment: Can you show the code you used to create the files, and tell us what kind of data they contain? If `.pkl` means you used the Python [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) module to write using `pickle.dump()`, you should be able to use `pickle.load()` to retrieve the object.

Comment: `import gzip
import _pickle as cPickle

f = gzip.open('C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/Data/train_set.pkl.gz','wb')
cPickle.load(train_set)
print(train_set)
f.close()` its not importing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should reconstruct your `train_set`:

```
with gzip.open('C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/Data/train_set.pkl.gz', 'rb') as f:
  train_set = cPickle.load(f)
```

Comment: `OSError: [Errno 9] peek() on write-only GzipFile object` received this error!

Comment: Oops, I copied `'wb'` from [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859435/how-would-i-import-pkl-gz-file-from-my-computer-into-a-python-program/42860527?noredirect=1#comment72825802_42859435) without thinking about what it implied :). Changed to `'rb'` and now it should work.

Comment: I changed it to rb as its in documentation...no effect

Comment: The error should be different though, right? (`f` is no longer "write-only"...)

Comment: @Sascha added. Please check

Comment: @WiLL_K You said the error was different from before, but you added the same error now. How should we follow this logic?

Comment: I don`t seem to have the hold of that code now. Sorry